# GoPro video lose color quality while exporting in Premiere CC

Tags: premiere

I am trying to solve this know gamma shift problem upon exporting from Adobe Premiere CC.
I have video recorded by GoPro Black edition.
The video quality is great but after compiling the video in a film by Premiere CC I loose
the quality of the color.
I have tried x264 but I still have this problem.

Probably I have not understood properly the reasons.
I do not think it is calibration problem, in fact (to my mind), if I open with vlc or quicktime, on the same computer (mac retina with maverick) the original video and the exported one I clearly notice the difference. 
WHY?, same computer, same movie, same player the only thing is that I open the file with Premiere CC and then exported it. 
I used the highest quality and I tried the H264 and x264 even with gamma correction of 2.2 the video does not look the same.

This is extremely annoying especially for underwater movies.

Please any help?
I can't get out of this problem.

Comment: Can you post screenshots demonstrating the difference you are seeing?

Comment: You may also find http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10305/upon-export-in-premiere-pro-colors-lose-saturation-when-previewing-in-quicktime relevant.  From your current question, I'm not sure it is a dupe, but there is a decent possibility it may be.

Answer (score 0):

This might indeed be a dupe of [Upon export in Premiere Pro, colors lose saturation when previewing in QuickTime](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10305/upon-export-in-premiere-pro-colors-lose-saturation-when-previewing-in-quicktime).

Are you using QuickTime .mov as your video container or MP4? If it's the former you will find your solution in the answer above.

If not, this might just have to do with your settings when encoding to h264. Try to export in a lossless codec and see if you get the same result. Then try an application like Handbrake with High Profile and see if you still get the same issue. H264 is a lossy codec and with a low-bitrate you can get washed out colors.